# How can I make double clicking on a DataGrid item open a more detailed view?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

*Please forgive any basic errors - I'm new to both Entity Framework and WPF.*

I have a DataGrid in a TabControl. The grid is bound to an Entity Framework model.

My end goal here is to be able to double click on a row in DataGrid and have a new tab open with a more detailed view of the same record.

So far I've been able to capture double click events:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="MemberRowDblClick" />
</Style>
```

But unable to identify the clicked-on row in my C#.

I'm also not sure if there's a smart way to get back to the data from the row. I.e. if I want to do something with the contents of the record, how easy is it to go back from a row index?

Sorry about asking two questions at once, but I have a sneaky suspicion that one will affect the other.

Comment: Off the top of my head, the `sender` parameter of your event handler *should* be the DataGridRow... is it not?

Comment: @DanJ That was just the nudge I needed. Casting sender to DataGridRow and it's child item to my model type allows me full access to the underlying data. If you want to put that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though declared as type `Object`, the `sender` parameter of your event handler contains the row that fired the event.

Casting `sender` to `DataGridRow` should give you what you need.