# How can I make a non-hyperlink item in a DataGrid clickable? C# WPF VisualStudio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, visual-studio-2015

How can I make a non-hyperlink item in a DataGrid clickable?

I'm creating a WPF program using C# in Visual Studio 2015 Community. I have successfully populated my DataGrid with data from a List. I would like to be able to click on a cell and display detailed information about the item in the cell. I have found how to click on the row and add a detail line below the clicked row, but that is not at all the behavior I am looking for.

The closest I have seen here are:
[How can I make double clicking on a DataGrid item open a more detailed view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776392/how-can-i-make-double-clicking-on-a-datagrid-item-open-a-more-detailed-view)
and
[Highlight one item in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352460/highlight-one-item-in-datagrid)

They both seem like good directions, but I have not been able to adapt them. I would greatly appreciate any input or direction to learning resources.

Thanks,
Eric

Here's what I'm trying to get to work before doing it full scale. I left the row detail in, but it is not actually what I would like to do.

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" Margin="84,310,194,69" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>                
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Plugin"
            Binding="{Binding name}"
            FontSize="14" 
            IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Developer"
            Binding="{Binding developer}"
            FontSize="14" 
            IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
                <TextBlock Text="Plugin: " HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="{Binding name}" Click="click" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
dataGrid2.ItemsSource = pluginList.plugins;
```

Comment: If its a server-side object you want to click on, wire up a onclick event to it when rendering it on the page.
This could call a client-side method to do what you want to do.
This is very general I know, but might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Terry. I might not be fully understanding how the WPF is structured, but It's not a hosted app. It's just local and I haven't found a way to assign a click event and handler to a cell. There seems to be a MouseDown Event that I can associate, but I haven't been able to figure out how to assign a custom Handler. It definitely generates an object reference (at least the row click does), but I haven't been able to figure out how to manipulate that either.

Comment: read this - [cell click in data grid](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html)

Comment: Muds - thank you! I think that is exactly what I am looking for. Once I've had a chance to try it later, I'll check back in.

Comment: @Muds! Perfect. A very understandable article and precisely what I was looking for! I don't know the exact ins and outs of this site yet, but I believe that if you offer your advice as an answer/solution, I can accept it so that it is easy for others to find. Thanks again.

Comment: @Eric - hit the up arrow on Muds answer below :)

Comment: @Terry - thanks for the info. I just did, but because I am so new to being registered here, it doesn't register publicly. I'll keep trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it would have been so convenient to have a CellClick event isn't ?

But this doesn't mean you can not find the element that received the click. Whenever mouse click happens on you can capture that and look for the original source and drill it up till the point you either receive a cell or it becomes top most element.

Then if you find source as cell, voila, you got the cell you clicked on.

A detailed explanation with example is provided here. please have a look.

[WPF DataGrid - detecting the column, cell and row that has been clicked](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html)